# Can two players play GTA 5 on the same console at the same time?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

My kids have an XBox 360 and they want to play GTA 5 at the same time on the same console. Is this possible? They also have XBox Live if that makes a difference.  They can't figure it out and I sure can't. If it is possible how do you do it?

Comment: For what it's worth: the only GTA game I know, that supports multiplayer on the same console is *GTA: San Andreas*, and even then it's quite hard to find the icon that launches the multiplayer aspect of the game.

Comment: @Jared - Has your question been answered? If so, mark your preferred answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 14):

GTA 5 doesn't have an offline multiplayer. 
This means you cannot play split screen with more than one player.
I wish there was an easy way to fix this but really its how the game was designed.

Its possible to play online multiplayer  in the same house but you need 2 consoles and 2 screens and 2 copies of the game.

Sorry for the bad news bears.

Answer (score 8):

### Core Features

- Local Co-Op: **Not Supported**
- Online Co-Op: **16**
- Players Local + Online Play: **Not Supported**
- LAN Play or System Link: **Not Supported**
- Co-Op Extras: **Co-Op Specific Content**

### The Co-Op Experience

Known also as GTA: Online, Grand Theft Auto V will ship with an online mode for up to 16 players. Complete missions like heists, robberies, and other events with friends. Content will change and be updated over time.

[Source](http://www.co-optimus.com/game/3090/xbox-360/grand-theft-auto-v.html)